# Using public keys for SSH authentication on several servers

Tags: ssh, sftp, key-authentication

I'm using a key pairs method for authenticating my sftp client on a remore server, that is a black box for me. So I've sent them the public key that I've generated with ssh-keygen command. 
So far should be fine :-)
My doubt is, in case the client should use the same method with a different server, I guess it is better to generate a new public key and it should be enough to store all the keys pairs (public and private ) in ~/.ssh for the user that is connecting (whetever ssh or sftp) with different servers. 
Is it the correct procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can use the same identity.pub file on all the machines you wish to log into. Then you just have the one password to remember. You only have to generate the one key pair.

If you want to use different passwords on different remote hosts, then by all means do what you are suggesting.

Generating multiple public keys with the same password seems like a pointless exercise.